# How to parallelize the DB row to Java object conversion in JPA (Java Persistence API)?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I am trying to read a million record and convert them to Java object using JPA.
We are getting the data within a minute but transforming them to Java object takes more time. Please let me know if there is a way to parallelize the process which converts each record to it's own Java representation, seems it is happening serially. We are using Hibernate framework (5.0.11) as the JPA Provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can't the `EntityManager` is single threaded.

One alternative would be to use Springs [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) with a [`ResultSetExtractor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html)

An alternative to splitting the work load after querying would be to query chunks in the first place and select each chunk in a separate thread.

*Note: a common pitfall of situations like this is that while the database might return the first row fast, it doesn't mean all rows are available and just fetching them all, i.e. iterating through the resultset might take considerably longer.*